# Special characters in mysql - charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have problem with MySQL charset.

Here is how it should look.

[image: how it should look] (https://ctrlv.cz/2VV2)

And here is what I get from db

[image: what I get from db] (https://ctrlv.cz/E7w6)

So which charset I should use? I try utf8,  utf8mb4...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mojibake.  This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Conversion:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY('★') USING latin1) USING utf8) = 'â˜…'
```